# How to achieve fire effect like this?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, fire

I'm in eevee 2.8 and trying to emulate this:  [Fire Gif](https://i.imgur.com/wU2L7tA.gif)

He explains how he does this with billboards, but I'm wondering this is the best approach in blender.

Is this (the fire and smoke) possible with metaballs? Or some kind of billboarding and dynamic material?

Comment: Do you just want to make a fire, or do you also want the strange 2d pattern coming off of the top like his?

Comment: @person132 Both yes - fire and smoke